# Flatened Firebase query in iOS issues

Tags: ios, database, swift, firebase

I have a "flatened" Firebase structure and trying to retrieve a dictionary of values from a "secondary" database member. In other words, I have a conversation which has a "to" cell which has the key to a business listing. With this key, I'm trying to retrieve the business listing and its children (url, description, title). For some reason, I can print the snapshot2.value and it responds with the expected value, but I can't pass it to my class initialization.

```
DataService.ds.REF_CONVOS.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
        self.convoListings.removeAll()
        self.convoListings = []
        //Data parsing from Firebase. The goal is to breakdown the data received and store in a local model.
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                for convo in userConvos {
                // Going into the children of the main object for the conversations.
                    //print("\(snap)")
                    if convo == snap.key {
                        //print(snap.value)
                        print(snap.value)
                        if let businessDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            businessName.removeAll()
                            let test = businessDict["to"] as? String
                            DataService.ds.REF_BusinessListing.childByAppendingPath(test).childByAppendingPath("title/").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot2 in
                                print(snapshot2.value)
                            })
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = ConvoListing(convoKey: key, dictionary: businessDict, businessName: self.test2)
                            self.convoListings.append(post)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting seems of:

```
DataService.ds.REF_BusinessListing.childByAppendingPath(test).childByAppendingPath("title/").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot2 in
     print(snapshot2.value)
})
let key = snap.key
let post = ConvoListing(convoKey: key, dictionary: businessDict, businessName: self.test2)
self.convoListings.append(post)
```

Keep in mind the `observeSingleEventOfType` loads the data asynchronously. For this reason, if you have code that needs the value that you loaded, you need to put that code in the block:

```
DataService.ds.REF_BusinessListing.childByAppendingPath(test).childByAppendingPath("title/").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot2 in
    print(snapshot2.value)
    let key = snap.key
    let post = ConvoListing(convoKey: key, dictionary: businessDict, businessName: self.test2)
    self.convoListings.append(post)
})
```